# Declarative macros - bracketed expressions can be followed by arbitrary matchers. Why?

Tags: rust, macros

I was experimenting with declarative macros and I thought about recreating F# sequence expressions using them.
First attempt triggered the compilation error:

```
macro_rules! genexp {
  (for $item:ident in $range:expr -> $expr:expr) => {
    $range.map(|$item| $expr)
  }
}

`$range:expr` is followed by `->`, which is not allowed for `expr` fragments
allowed there are: `=>`, `,` or `;`rustc
```

However, following code compiles and works just fine:

```
macro_rules! genexp {
  (for $item:ident in [$range:expr] -> $expr:expr) => {
    $range.map(|$item| $expr)
  }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = genexp!(for x in [0..20] -> x * x);
    println!("{:?}", foo.collect::<Vec<_>>())
}

//OUTPUT: [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361]
```

My question is, why?  [Macros By Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html) section in Rust Reference states that:

> - `expr` and `stmt` may only be followed by one of: `=>`, `,`, or `;`.

I see no info about special treatment of various brackets or other delimiters.

Comment: Probably because those are the only tokens that aren't valid at the top level of an expression or statement. Putting the whole thing in brackets makes it unambiguous when the expression/statement ends.

Comment: One other thing that I noticed is that surrounding expression with any brackets effectively turns it into token tree (tt) - token tree definition is "either singular token or any number of token trees inside any brackets". And token trees can be followed by anything, as they are unambiguous.
I feel like documentation could be a little more explicit here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$range:expr ->
```

The Rust language could be expanded in the future where `->` becomes a valid part of an expression. The idea is that macros are unambiguously future-compatible with updates to Rust, so this is disallowed to be conservative.

```
[$range:expr] ->
```

The Rust language will never be expanded with features that involve unbalanced brackets/parents/braces `[](){}`. Therefore, when the Rust parser sees `[` it can scan for the matching `]` immediately. It is thus unambiguous which portion of this macro is the expression, and where the expression stops and the `] ->` occurs, even in the face of future language expansions.

Comment: This doesn't really explain why the compiler says only `=>`, `;` or `,` would be accepted after an expression, whereas `]` would be too, does it?

Comment: @BlackBeans `]` wouldn't necessarily be "accepted after an expression", it's more that it's handled at a stage before the expression is ever parsed. At least that's how I view it, maybe the error message could be improved.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "it's handled at a stage before the expression is ever parsed"? I feel that explaining this particular point would help understand why the compiler says what is sayd.

Comment: @BlackBeans *"Therefore, when the Rust parser sees [ it can scan for the matching ] immediately."* Rust only allows matching pairs of brackets, so you can view bracket matching happening at a stage earlier than full parsing. I'm not claiming this is what the compiler actually does, but that it's simply a model that allows you to understand why the above is unambiguous for any expression.